# Replacing bytes in NSData

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I want to replace some bytes in an NSData object.
I first want to search for it, then replace it, like the replaceOccurrencesOfString:WithString: method for NSStrings.
What's the right way of doing so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html